# Unknown parameters in pytest.mark: test_cases

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to improve some testing code from unknown developer.
I've found strange method call for pytest.mark object.

```
test_natural_sort_key = pytest.mark.test_cases(
    ["given", "expected"],
    dict(
        __id="letters only",
        given=["b", "a", "c"],
       expected=['a', 'b', 'c'],
   ),
```

But when I import mark from pytest in Python prompt, no such property is available.

```
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pytest
>>> m = pytest.mark
>>> dir(m)
['__annotations__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__
', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_config', '_markers']
>>> type(m)
<class '_pytest.mark.structures.MarkGenerator'>
>>>
```

What I am missing? Should `mark` generate an object with mentioned method? (it doesn't)

After comments, I've figured out that it's similar to:

```
import pytest

def _test_natural_sort_key(given, expected):
    ...

@pytest.mark.test_cases
def test_natural_sort_key():
    all_cases = [
    dict(
        __id="letters only",
        given=["b", "a", "c"],
        expected=['a', 'b', 'c'],)]

    for one_case in all_cases:
        given = one_case['given']
        expected = one_case['expected']
        _test_natural_sort_key(given, expected)
```

Is that right?

Comment: The mark generator is a decorator maker. Is the decorator `test_natural_sort_key` used anywhere?

Comment: Yes, it is used, but not as a decorator, but as a fn call:
    test_natural_sort_key(some_really_sorting_fn)

Comment: That is still a decorator. It's just applying the decoration manually, instead of the @ syntax sugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pytest.mark` accepts any attribute name you look up on it. The idea is that you can use any custom marker you like, and select tests using the `-m` cli option. For example:

```
# your tests
@pytest.mark.foo
def test_test():
    ...

#cli: will only execute tests marked "foo"
pytest -m foo
```

Pytest will usually complain about custom markers that are not registered in its config (`pytest.ini`, `pyproject.toml` etc.).

Marks can take parameters, which in turn can be used in pytest fixtures or hooks, like [pytest_collection_modify_items](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems).

`pytest.mark.test_cases` is not built in and I couldn't find a plugin that provides it.

I'd first look in all relevant `conftest.py` files if that marker is used. If not, it may be provided by an installed pytest plugin.